# Dots and arrows. Is this true?

Tags: graph-theory

Imagine a graph with $n$ dots and $2n$ connecting arrows that meet the following rules:

Rule 1) Every dot has at least one arrow going into it.
Rule 2) Every dot has two arrows going out, each going to another dot.
Rule 3) You can travel along the arrows from any dot to any other dot.

Then, is it true that if I add a dot that meets rules 1 & 2, the new graph will automatically follow rule 3, i.e. I can still travel from any dot to any other dot.

Comment: What do you have in mind when you say "add a dot that meets rules 1 & 2"?  Does the arrow coming into it mean that the dot that arrow comes from now has three arrows going out, or does it mean you choose a dot and *redirect* one of its two arrows?  If the former, the new graph certainly satisfies rule 3; if the latter, there are easy examples where it doesn't.

Comment: If you are using this for induction, then be aware that you can duplicate your graph (so still meet 1 and 2 and have twice as many connecting arrows as dots) but the combined graph will be disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can show this as follows:

> Let the new dot be called $d$, and let the new arrows be $c \to d, d \to e, d \to f$.
>
> Then we can travel *from* $d$ to any dot through $e$ or $f$, and travel *to* $d$ from any dot through $c$.

However, the new graph is *not* of the same form as the original. Namely, to add $d$, we have to introduce *three* new arrows, one into $d$, and two out of $d$. Therefore, we have a graph with $n+1$ nodes and $2n+3$ edges.

Concretely, the node $c$ now has *three* arrows going out of it — two to nodes in the existing graph, and the new one to $d$. Therefore, the new graph as a whole does no longer satisfy rule 2.

---

In fact, the flaw is fundamental. For, the theorem:

> Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ nodes such that:
>
> 1. Every node has at least one arrow going into it;
> 2. Every node has precisely two arrows going out of it
>
> Then there is a path between any two nodes of $G$.

for which this seems an attempt at a proof by induction, is **false**. Consider the following counterexample (created using [Directed Graph Editor](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347)):

[image]

We see we cannot travel from $0$ to $4$.

Comment: Oh dear. I think you have shown me that my inductive "proof" is wrong, because, as you said, c now as 3 arrows going out of it, and it is only allowed 2. So we can't simply add d, we have to "repoint" a preexisting arrow to it, which changes the original system. I should have stated Rule 2 as "Every dot has EXACTLY two arrows going out..." My bad. So let me rephrase my question: Is it true that for a system of n dots following rules 1 & 2 you can travel from any dot to any other dot? If it is true how do you prove that? And thank you for your patience.

Comment: @odenlou, easy counterexample to your rephrased question here:  two *disjoint* triangles, each with arrows going from each vertex to the other two.

Comment: It is certainly going the extra mile to provide a color diagram in response. Again, I thank you (and also Barry) for providing this counter-example. So I consider this question answered in full, but allow me just one more. What happens if to Rules 1 and 2 we add another, say, Rule 0, which is that no arrows can be double ended i.e. if an arrow goes directly from a to b it is not allowed to go from b to a. I understand this is a very different question, but I am most interested in this also.

Comment: @odenlou That would be more appropriate as a new question, because it is very different in nature. Probably best to link to this one, so that people get the context.

Comment: Agreed. How do I give you credit for having given such a quick and comprehensive response?

Comment: Under the vote count, you see a grey checkmark which, when clicked, marks an answer as "accepted". Cf. the [Help Centre](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

now there is a system of $n$ dots , now we are adding one more which we are calling $x$ , following rule 1 and 2 . so there is one arrow going into it , lets say it comes from an arrow called $a$ and it has two arrows going out , lets say one of them is going to $b$ . so now we know in the prior system we could travel from any 1 dot to another . so now to go to $x$ from the system ,we can always go to $a$ and then through that to $x$ and to go to a random point from $x$ we can always go to $b$ from $x$ and then go to any desired point. thus we can say $x$ follows rule 3.

Comment: First, thank you for taking time to answer my question. Its seems your answer is "Yes"! If so does this mean that for ANY systems of n dots that follow rules 1 and 2, you can travel from any dot to any dot?