# Graph with $n$ nodes and $2n$ arrows

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a directed graph on $n$ nodes such that:

1. Every node has at least one arrow going into it
2. Every node has precisely two arrows going out of it.
3. Between two nodes there is an arrow in at most one direction.

Under these conditions, is it true that there is a path between any two nodes of G? If so, how does one prove it?

(I want to thank Mr Farin and Barry for helping to clarify my question; the previous one is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1137643/43351).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not true.

For example, in the following, there is no path from the right pentagon to the left pentagon.

[image]

*Added:* Perhaps a simpler example

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I officially indicate I am fully satisfied with your reply?

Answer (score 2):

While Henry provided some easily verified counterexamples, I accepted the challenge and tried to find one with the minimal number of nodes. I think it's eight, as exemplified by:

[image]

Any unreachable section will need at least three nodes, because of the first rule. The distinctness criterion for the outgoing and incoming arrows prohibits a graph on four nodes satisfying the rules, so we need five additional nodes to complete the job.

Comment: You read my mind! I was just trying to figure out what the smallest counter example would be.

Comment: Although I am checking off Henry's response, Mr Farin's is also very helpful. I wish I could check BOTH of them. I gave a check to Mr Farin for his help on a previous question. He taught me that dots are actually nodes and to say Path instead of Travel. Much appreciated.

Comment: @odenlou Always a pleasure to help those eager to learn :).